# LINQ/EF declaring a temp variable for performance

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a database query. I can make go nice and fast with raw SQL but I'd really like to do something similar in LINQ

```
declare @ruleInstanceCount int
select @ruleInstanceCount
    = (select count(distinct(gri.RuleInstance_Id))
       from [Group] g  
       left join GroupRuleInstance gri on g.id = gri.Group_Id
       where g.name= @groupName)

SELECT cache.EntityKey
from RuleInstanceCurrentMembershipCacheItem cache
left join RuleInstance ri on ri.id = cache.RuleInstanceId 
left join GroupRuleInstance gri on ri.id = gri.RuleInstance_Id
left join [Group] g on g.id = gri.Group_Id 
where cache.IsMember = 1 and g.Name = @groupName 
group by cache.EntityKey
HAVING  count(cache.RuleInstanceId) = @ruleInstanceCount
order by cache.EntityKey
```

Yay SQL is really fast because I can declare a variable and use it later

this has been my best attempt so far with LINQ but its about 50x slower

```
from g in ctx.Groups
where g.Name == groupName
let ruleCount = g.Rules.Select(r => r.Id).Distinct().Count()
from ri in g.Rules
from mem in ri
    .CurrentMembership
    .Where(m => m.IsMember)
    .Select(m => new { m.EntityKey, m.RuleInstanceId, ruleCount })
group mem by mem.EntityKeyinto ekGroup
let ruleCount = ekGroup.Any() ? ekGroup.FirstOrDefault().ruleCount : 0
where ekGroup.Count() == ruleCount
orderby ekGroup.Key
select ekGroup.Key
```

The generated SQL is a bit of a mess (I can post it if required) but there are 2 important differences between this and my hand coded SQL.

1. There's no declare statement - which means it does the actual @ruleInstanceCount over and over.
2. There's no having clause when it does the comparison of how many times it saw the rule instance.

**I think its slow because of 1 but I don't know any way to do a declare or similar so that it only executes the count once.**

[image]

**Edit:**

As requested here is the generated SQL

```
SELECT 
    [Project13].[EntityKey] AS [EntityKey]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project12].[EntityKey] AS [EntityKey]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project11].[EntityKey] AS [EntityKey], 
            [Project11].[C1] AS [C1], 
            [Project11].[C2] AS [C2], 
            [Project11].[C3] AS [C3], 
            (SELECT 
                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                FROM   [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent17]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[GroupRuleInstance] AS [Extent18] ON [Extent17].[Id] = [Extent18].[Group_Id]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[RuleInstanceCurrentMembershipCacheItem] AS [Extent19] ON ([Extent18].[RuleInstance_Id] = [Extent19].[RuleInstanceId]) AND ([Extent19].[IsMember] = 1)
                WHERE ((([Extent17].[Name] = @p__linq__0) AND ( NOT ([Extent17].[Name] IS NULL OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent17].[Name] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND ([Project11].[EntityKey] = [Extent19].[EntityKey])) AS [C4]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Project10].[EntityKey] AS [EntityKey], 
                [Project10].[C1] AS [C1], 
                [Project10].[C2] AS [C2], 
                (SELECT 
                    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                    FROM   [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent14]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[GroupRuleInstance] AS [Extent15] ON [Extent14].[Id] = [Extent15].[Group_Id]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[RuleInstanceCurrentMembershipCacheItem] AS [Extent16] ON ([Extent15].[RuleInstance_Id] = [Extent16].[RuleInstanceId]) AND ([Extent16].[IsMember] = 1)
                    WHERE ((([Extent14].[Name] = @p__linq__0) AND ( NOT ([Extent14].[Name] IS NULL OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent14].[Name] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND ([Project10].[EntityKey] = [Extent16].[EntityKey])) AS [C3]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Project9].[EntityKey] AS [EntityKey], 
                    [Project9].[C1] AS [C1], 
                    (SELECT 
                        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                        FROM   [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent11]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[GroupRuleInstance] AS [Extent12] ON [Extent11].[Id] = [Extent12].[Group_Id]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[RuleInstanceCurrentMembershipCacheItem] AS [Extent13] ON ([Extent12].[RuleInstance_Id] = [Extent13].[RuleInstanceId]) AND ([Extent13].[IsMember] = 1)
                        WHERE ((([Extent11].[Name] = @p__linq__0) AND ( NOT ([Extent11].[Name] IS NULL OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent11].[Name] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND ([Project9].[EntityKey] = [Extent13].[EntityKey])) AS [C2]
                    FROM ( SELECT 
                        [Project7].[EntityKey] AS [EntityKey], 
                        CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
                            1 AS [C1]
                            FROM   [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent8]
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[GroupRuleInstance] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent8].[Id] = [Extent9].[Group_Id]
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[RuleInstanceCurrentMembershipCacheItem] AS [Extent10] ON ([Extent9].[RuleInstance_Id] = [Extent10].[RuleInstanceId]) AND ([Extent10].[IsMember] = 1)
                            WHERE ((([Extent8].[Name] = @p__linq__0) AND ( NOT ([Extent8].[Name] IS NULL OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent8].[Name] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND ([Project7].[EntityKey] = [Extent10].[EntityKey])
                        )) THEN [Project7].[C1] ELSE 0 END AS [C1]
                        FROM ( SELECT 
                            [Project6].[EntityKey] AS [EntityKey], 
                            [Project6].[C1] AS [C1]
                            FROM ( SELECT 
                                [Project2].[EntityKey] AS [EntityKey], 
                                (SELECT TOP (1) 
                                    [Project4].[C1] AS [C1]
                                    FROM    (SELECT 
                                        [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id], 
                                        (SELECT 
                                            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                                            FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                                                [Extent5].[RuleInstance_Id] AS [RuleInstance_Id]
                                                FROM [dbo].[GroupRuleInstance] AS [Extent5]
                                                WHERE [Extent4].[Id] = [Extent5].[Group_Id]
                                            )  AS [Distinct2]) AS [C1]
                                        FROM [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent4]
                                        WHERE (([Extent4].[Name] = @p__linq__0) AND ( NOT ([Extent4].[Name] IS NULL OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent4].[Name] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL)) ) AS [Project4]
                                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[GroupRuleInstance] AS [Extent6] ON [Project4].[Id] = [Extent6].[Group_Id]
                                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[RuleInstanceCurrentMembershipCacheItem] AS [Extent7] ON ([Extent6].[RuleInstance_Id] = [Extent7].[RuleInstanceId]) AND ([Extent7].[IsMember] = 1)
                                    WHERE [Project2].[EntityKey] = [Extent7].[EntityKey]) AS [C1]
                                FROM ( SELECT 
                                    [Distinct1].[EntityKey] AS [EntityKey]
                                    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                                        [Extent3].[EntityKey] AS [EntityKey]
                                        FROM   [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent1]
                                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[GroupRuleInstance] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Group_Id]
                                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[RuleInstanceCurrentMembershipCacheItem] AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent2].[RuleInstance_Id] = [Extent3].[RuleInstanceId]) AND ([Extent3].[IsMember] = 1)
                                        WHERE (([Extent1].[Name] = @p__linq__0) AND ( NOT ([Extent1].[Name] IS NULL OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent1].[Name] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
                                    )  AS [Distinct1]
                                )  AS [Project2]
                            )  AS [Project6]
                        )  AS [Project7]
                    )  AS [Project9]
                )  AS [Project10]
            )  AS [Project11]
        )  AS [Project12]
        WHERE (([Project12].[C2] = [Project12].[C1]) AND ( NOT ([Project12].[C3] IS NULL OR [Project12].[C1] IS NULL))) OR (([Project12].[C4] IS NULL) AND ([Project12].[C1] IS NULL))
    )  AS [Project13]
    ORDER BY [Project13].[EntityKey] ASC
```

And model:

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RuleInstance> Rules { get; set; }
}

public class RuleInstance
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RuleInstanceCurrentMembershipCacheItem> CurrentMembership { get; set; }
}

public class RuleInstanceCurrentMembershipCacheItem
{
    public Guid RuleInstanceId { get; set; }
    public int EntityKey { get; set; }
    public RuleInstance RuleInstance { get; set; }
    public bool IsMember { get; set; }
}
```

Edit:

Based on @MarcinJuraszek's answer I settled on the following:

```
var ruleInstances = from g in ctx.Groups
            from ri in g.Rules
            where g.Name == groupName
            select ri.Id;

var cache = (   from g in ctx.Groups
        where g.Name == groupName
        from ri in g.Rules
        from mem in ri.CurrentMembership
        where mem.IsMember
        group mem by mem.AnimalKey into akGroup
        where akGroup.Count() == ruleInstances.Distinct().Count()
        orderby akGroup.Key
        select akGroup.Key).ToArray();
```

it produces the following query

```
SELECT 
[Project4].[EntityKey] AS [EntityKey]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [EntityKey]
    FROM     (SELECT 
        [Extent3].[EntityKey] AS [K1], 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1], 
        COUNT(1) AS [A2], 
        COUNT(1) AS [A3]
        FROM   [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[GroupRuleInstance] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Group_Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[RuleInstanceCurrentMembershipCacheItem] AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent2].[RuleInstance_Id] = [Extent3].[RuleInstanceId]) AND ([Extent3].[IsMember] = 1)
        WHERE (([Extent1].[Name] = @p__linq__0) AND ( NOT ([Extent1].[Name] IS NULL OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent1].[Name] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
        GROUP BY [Extent3].[EntityKey] ) AS [GroupBy1]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent5].[RuleInstance_Id] AS [RuleInstance_Id]
            FROM  [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent4]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[GroupRuleInstance] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[Id] = [Extent5].[Group_Id]
            WHERE (([Extent4].[Name] = @p__linq__1) AND ( NOT ([Extent4].[Name] IS NULL OR @p__linq__1 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent4].[Name] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL))
        )  AS [Distinct1] ) AS [GroupBy2]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent7].[RuleInstance_Id] AS [RuleInstance_Id]
            FROM  [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent6]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[GroupRuleInstance] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[Id] = [Extent7].[Group_Id]
            WHERE (([Extent6].[Name] = @p__linq__1) AND ( NOT ([Extent6].[Name] IS NULL OR @p__linq__1 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent6].[Name] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL))
        )  AS [Distinct2] ) AS [GroupBy3]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
            [Extent9].[RuleInstance_Id] AS [RuleInstance_Id]
            FROM  [dbo].[Group] AS [Extent8]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[GroupRuleInstance] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent8].[Id] = [Extent9].[Group_Id]
            WHERE (([Extent8].[Name] = @p__linq__1) AND ( NOT ([Extent8].[Name] IS NULL OR @p__linq__1 IS NULL))) OR (([Extent8].[Name] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL))
        )  AS [Distinct3] ) AS [GroupBy4]
    WHERE (([GroupBy1].[A1] = [GroupBy2].[A1]) AND ( NOT ([GroupBy1].[A2] IS NULL OR [GroupBy3].[A1] IS NULL))) OR (([GroupBy1].[A3] IS NULL) AND ([GroupBy4].[A1] IS NULL))
)  AS [Project4]
ORDER BY [Project4].[EntityKey] ASC
```

Comment: You should show the SQL. I think your LINQ looks totally different then SQL you're trying to emulate.

Comment: And another question: how do your model classes look like?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek ive posted the generated SQL + model as requested :) im pretty sure most of the garbage is to do with the count query as if i do what Alexander is suggesting the statement is very simple and exactly what you would expect

Comment: OK, I have one more question. Are you sure the performance is different when you use temporary variable and when you don't do it?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek as in if i put the count statement inline in the main query? one sec ill check

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek no they are nearly identical

Comment: That's because SQL optimizer is smart enough to calculate that inner expression only once. You can check this looking at query execution plan.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek that in LINQ also performs nice and fast, i didnt know it would be smart enough to cache that. Any idea if EF even supports declaring a temp variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try with following:

```
var ctx = new Context();

var groupName = "something";

var ruleInstances = from g in ctx.Groups
                    from gri in g.Rules.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where g.Name == groupName
                    select gri.Id;

var keys = from c in ctx.CurrentMembership
           let ri = c.RuleInstance
           from g in ri.Groups.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where c.IsMember && g.Name == groupName
           group c by c.EntityKey into g
           where g.Select(x => x.RuleInstanceId).Count() == ruleInstances.Distinct().Count()
           orderby g.Key
           select g.Key;
```

It should give you SQL quite close to:

```
SELECT cache.EntityKey
from RuleInstanceCurrentMembershipCacheItem cache
left join RuleInstance ri on ri.id = cache.RuleInstanceId 
left join GroupRuleInstance gri on ri.id = gri.RuleInstance_Id
left join [Group] g on g.id = gri.Group_Id 
where cache.IsMember = 1 and g.Name = @groupName 
group by cache.EntityKey
HAVING  count(cache.RuleInstanceId) =
       (select count(distinct(gri.RuleInstance_Id))
       from [Group] g  
       left join GroupRuleInstance gri on g.id = gri.Group_Id
       where g.name= @groupName)
order by cache.EntityKey
```

I assumed your context looks close to that one:

```
public class Context
{
    public IQueryable<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<RuleInstance> Rules { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<RuleInstanceCurrentMembershipCacheItem> CurrentMembership { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @LukeMcGregor You've accepted the answer so fast I'm not really sure you tried the solution. Can you confirm that generated SQL looks quite as expected?

Comment: I had already run it on my own, the SQL isnt quite as nice as that listed, it uses a set of cross joins instead of the having clause but performance wise its pretty similar, approx 20% slower but it is going through EF

Comment: Actually i take it back i did my query in the other order, mine performs much faster, 4ms vs 100ms for yours, the generated sql is very similar but it has an extra left join. your query looks functionally identical to mine, im not too sure what makes mine so much faster.

Comment: You should look at query execution plan.

Comment: the QP says that the additional time is in an index seek and merge join for the left outer join which is present in your query but not in mine, im not too sure whats putting it there though

Answer (score 2):

Your LINQ more different than your SQL. First off all, in your SQL you have two queries, but in LINQ you are trying to combine them in one. Why? I have tried to convert your SQL to LINQ, and i think, the generated SQL will be simular the raw SQL:

```
var ruleInstanceCount = (
    from g in Group
    join gri in GroupRuleInstance on g.id equals gri.Group_Id into gris
    from gri in gris.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where g.name == groupName
    group gri by gri.RuleInstance_Id into grp
    select new 
        {
            Id = grp.Key
        }
    ).Count();

var items = (
    from cache in RuleInstanceCurrentMembershipCacheItem
    join ri from RuleInstance on cache.RuleInstanceId equals ri.id into ris
    from ri in ris.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join gri from GroupRuleInstance on ri.id equals gri.RuleInstance_Id into gris
    from gri in gris.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join g from Group on gri.Group_Id equals g.id into gs
    from g in gs.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where cache.IsMember == 1 && g.Name = groupName
    group cache by cache.EntityKey into grp
    select new 
        {
            Count = grp.Count(x => x.RuleInstanceId),
            EntityKey = grp.Key
        })
        .Where(x => x.Count == ruleInstanceCount)
        .OrderBy(x => x.EntityKey);
```

Comment: It will make 2 separate queries into DB.

Comment: Yes, and what the problem? The author's problem is performance, two simple queries much better than one big.

Comment: @Alexander Splitting the query in two will result in 2 synchronous round trips to the database which is never going to perform as fast as a single query (my raw SQL case). My question isnt really how do i make my linq query perform faster its `can you declare a temp variable in linq?` having said this what you are proposing is certainly much faster than what i have posted (hence +1)

Comment: @Luke McGregor, about performance one big query, i want to disagree with you). In any case, LINQ is not SQL, and have some limitations. You can declare temp variable (you did it with `let`), but in this case, LINQ will generate for you monstrous SQL.

Comment: @Alexander you cant use let here as it goes out of scope when i do the groupby clause